# Discrete maths Predicate Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

1. ( ∀x(P(x)→Q(x)) )      →  ( ∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x)) )
2. ( ∃x(P(x))→∃x(Q(x)) )   →  ( ∃x(P(x)→Q(x)) )

I got these in my some test series,i was not able to prove.Please help me how to prove that this implication holds,if possible please explain why converse doesn't hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what formal proof system you have to use, but here are some informal proofs that hopefully you will be able to formalize:

I. This statement says: 'If all P's are Q's, then if everything is a P, then everything is a Q'. To prove this, do a conditional proof: Assume that all P's are Q's, and show that if everything is a P, then everything is a Q. And since that last statement is another conditional, we'll do a conditional proof for that one as well: Assume that everything is a P, and show that everything is a Q. Well, if everything is a P, and if all P's are Q's, then everything is a Q. Done!

Schematically (and pseudo-formally)

1. $\qquad \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ (Conditional Proof Assumption 1)
2. $\qquad \qquad \forall x P(x)$ (Conditional Proof Assumption 2)
3. $\qquad \qquad \qquad$ ... [consider any arbitrary object $a$]
4. $\qquad \qquad \qquad P(a)$ by 2
5. $\qquad \qquad \qquad P(a) \rightarrow Q(a)$ by 1
6. $\qquad \qquad \qquad Q(a)$ by 4 and 5
7. $\qquad \qquad \forall x Q(x)$  by 3 through 6
8. $\qquad \forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ Conditional proof 2 through 7
9. $\qquad \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x))$ Conditional proof 1 through 8

Why does the converse ($(\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x))\rightarrow \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ ) not hold? Here is a simple counterexample: take as the domain natural numbers, interpret $P(x)$ as $x$ is an even number, and $Q(x)$ as $x$ is an odd number. Since not all numbers are even, $\forall x P(x)$ is false, but any conditional with a false antecedent is true, so this means that $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ is (vacuously) true. But obvviously, even numbers are not odd numbers, so $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ is false. So, $(\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x))\rightarrow \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ is false.

II. This one is best proven using a proof by contradiction. Here is a pseudo-formal proof:

1. $\qquad \exists x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x Q(x)$ (Conditional Proof Assumption)
2. $\qquad \qquad \neg \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ (Proof by Contradiction Assumption)
3. $\qquad \qquad \forall x \neg (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ (Quantifier Negation on 2)
4. $\qquad \qquad \forall x (P(x) \land \neg Q(x)) $ (Implication Negation on 3)
5. $\qquad \qquad \forall x P(x) \land \forall x \neg Q(x) $ (Distribution $\forall$ over $\land$ on 4)
6. $\qquad \qquad \forall x P(x)$ (Simplification 5)
7. $\qquad \qquad \forall x \neg Q(x)$ (Simplification 5)
8. $\qquad \qquad \exists x P(x)$ (Implied by 6, assuming domain is not empty, which is what most logics assume))
9. $\qquad \qquad \exists x Q(x)$ (from 1 and 8)
10. $\qquad \qquad \neg \exists x Q(x)$ (Quantifier Negation on 7)
11. $\qquad \qquad \bot$ (from 9 and 10)
12. $\qquad \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ (Proof by Contradiction 2 through 11)
13. $(\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x Q(x)) \rightarrow \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ (Conditional Proof 1 through 12)

For a counterexample to the converse $\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \rightarrow (\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x Q(x)) $, pick some domain where some, but not all, objects are $P$'s, but nothing is a $Q$. For example, take the natural numbers again as the domain, let $P(x)$ again be $x$ is even, and let $Q(x)$ be $x$ is a unicorn. Then the antecedent  $\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ is true, since there are some numbers that are not even, thus making the inside conditional (vacuously) true, The consequent $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x Q(x)$ is false however, since $\exists x P(x) $ is true (yes, there are some even numbers), but $\exists x Q(x)$ is false (no, no numbers are unicorns). Hence, under this interpretation  $\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \rightarrow (\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x Q(x)) $ is false.

Comment: Thank you.I was looking for this kind of explanation for understanding.:)